# How to install libnettle6 on Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: 20.04

By default it comes with libnettle7.

I'm using Windows Subsystem for Linux so I only have the command line and I have no idea how to install a version fo libnettle from ubuntu 18 using the command line.

Can anyone help

Comment: Are you sure you need an older version?  Trying to downgrade packages is a recipe for trouble, especially with libraries as they tend to have other packages dependent on them. It's not common for a newer version to not support something it supported in a prior version.  Especially since this is a cryptographic library, an older version might have security vulnerabilities.  To avoid the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), I suggest that you ask about the actual problem you face: the problem that has caused you to ask for this particular library.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I need to use a binary that specifically looks for `NETTLE_6` and is crashing at present

Answer (score 0):

**I grabbed the file from here**

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nettle/libnettle6_3.2-1ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb

**And then installed it**

sudo apt install ~/downloads/libnettle6_3.2-1ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb

I was using it to get aria2_1.33.1-1_amd64 installed to support uget plugin Firefox

**It worked perfectly for me on Ubuntu 20.10 as shown below**

*lsb_release -a*

> No LSB modules are available.
>
> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
>
> Description:  Ubuntu 20.10
>
> Release:  20.10
>
> Codename: groovy